# Bandwidth limiter from virtual network set on the dns router

Tags: vpn, dns, network-administration, bandwidth, vpn-server

I want to play video game without lag(high latency ms), my router has no qos function, and I have no condition to buy a new one.

is possible to make a virtual network for managing the bandwidth, in which the virtual network clone each particular ipv4/ipv6 and set this in dns input on router setting using a dns server sync with the virtual network?

is there any dns vpn service, software, that acts this way? or similiar?

some kind of hamachi + netlimiter + opendns

Comment: What's different than "hamachi + netlimiter + opendns" in your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat.

I have a 6mb DSL plan.  Comes in to my ISP supplied router, which has my 10.1.1.0/24 network and DHCP is turned OFF.  This is where my desktop is (at 10.1.1.10).  I have a Pi, at 10.1.1.2 with a second network card (usb dongle) at 10.1.2.1.  The Pi is running Raspbian, and is configured as a open router, as well as caching DNS and DNS for a fake LAN-only domain, and has DHCP going for both the 10.1.1.0 and 10.1.2.0 networks.

To limit total bandwidth use on the 10.1.2.0 network, I use `wondershaper` on the secondary network device.

So to keep it on topic - linux, bind9, iptables, isc-dhcp-server, wondershaper and some shell scripts.

Comment: I do not want to limit directly on the devices, but by a virtual network that connects through the dns of the router.